# Save BizTalk EDI message to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm very new to BizTalk 2013 programming.

I have created a BizTalk solution to read 204 X12 file and convert them to XML.
I want to save the XML data to a SQL Server table.

Is there any way to specify orchestration should start after EDI send is complete?

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you have your tables designed? Or you simply want to store the xml as is in SQL table?

Comment: I have a table designed which should store the fields extracted from the edi message(xml file) in columns. Thank your very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is *already built into BizTalk Server*.  You don't need to do anything.

See: [EDI and AS2 Status Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226463.aspx)

Set this up and 95% it will meet all of your requirements.  If there are any gaps, come back and we can offer other recommendations.

Most of the time, custom logging or archiving causes more problems than it solves.  Believer me, I've seen it too many cases.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727695.aspx.                     With the help of the above link i'm able to read the file and send 997 acknowledgement.  Next what I need is the xml file content should be stored in a sql table.

Comment: Like the EDI, what you're asking for is already built into BizTalk.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561912.aspx  But please be warned, you probably don't need to do this.  Having the Xml is of little value to the business.

Comment: Hi Johns-305 I created a biztalk project (that refers to EDI project) which will receive the x12 text file using edi receive and convert it to xml. I created another project to read the xml file and map it to sql insert sp using WCF-Custom adapter. Now I'm facing multiple schema issue (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b249f29-d1c3-4cc6-a543-3a32a59f4954/cannot-locate-document-specification-because-multiple-schemas-matched-the-message-type?forum=biztalkgeneral) I think I need to create a receive pipeline with EDI disassembler.  Please let me know if any better idea you have.

Comment: Since this is a separate issue, please start a new specific thread.